# How to uninstall gmail app on android without root

Tags: gmail, uninstallation, root-access, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to remove the preinstalled Gmail app (not account, I meant the app itself). My web searches yield methods to remove gmail account, not the app. Just to add, I had managed to finish the default android setup/installation (when the phone was 1st activated after purchase) by using a non-gmail account. It worked just fine til today (almost 1 year).

Gmail/Gmaps/Photos/Other G-Apps is just another app in android. Just quite puzzled why it can't be uninstalled just like any other app. I'd prefer a non-root removal solution if possible.

If it is not, appreciate if you can include a way to 'undo' the root after the app removal. Terminal based or debug mode solution are still acceptable as long as the phone can still be switched back to 'non-root' mode later. Fyi, I'd prefer the phone to operate in 'non-root' whenever possible as a (tiny) phone cybersecurity effort.

p/s : [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52682/should-i-update-those-pre-installed-programs-that-i-never-use) post share a method to disable it.. but not (afaik) uninstall.

Comment: [`adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gm`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204485/96277). See [What are the differences between a system app and user app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17871/96277).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Platform-tools on your computer (google if don't know how to)
Enable Developer Options on your phone (google if don't know how to)

Then enable USB debugging in developer options

Then give the command

`adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.google.android.gm`

Comment: I just learnt : `shell` (run emulator console command) `pm` (package manager) `uninstall` (removes package) `--user` (what's this means/for?) `com.google.android.gm` (target app) | off all the reference I had encountered, non explains the info for `--user`under `pm uninstall`   command |my [ref](http://android-doc.github.io/tools/help/shell.html) | Thanks a lot for the great assist, really appreciate it. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ --user 0 implies admin user on your phone. For example, if you have multiple users, --user 1 implies the second user. SO here, uninstallling an app for --user 0 implies removing it for admin user or rather the first user on the device

Comment: oic.. thanks @karthiknair.. got it.